# sweetalert2がIEで動かない

Tags: javascript

chromeで動作確認したsweetalert2がIEで動きません。

```
<!-- Include a polyfill for ES6 Promises (optional) for IE11, UC Browser and Android browser support -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.js"></script>
```

IE対応のために上記の記述を入れたのですが、動きませんでした。
これだけでは不十分ということでしょうか？

Comment: IEというのはIE11のことでしょうか？ [GitHub](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2)にはIE10以下のサポートは無いと書いてあります。　IE11の場合は確かにこれで動くはずですが、これだけでは何が問題なのか回答するのは難しいと思います。どのようなエラーメッセージが出現しているのかを追記していただけると回答が可能になるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。IE11です。動かないというのは具体的に言うと、ボタンをクリックしても何の反応も無い、ということです。

Comment: : 'Promise' は定義されていません。: 'module' は定義されていません。エラーメッセージはこの２つが出ているようです。`<script src="https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-7.0.4.min.js"></script>`これも入れてみましたが変化ありません。

Comment: `<script src="https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-7.0.4.min.js"></script>`これをsweetalert2より先に読み込むようにしたら「Promiseは定義されません」エラーは消えました。代わりにアロー関数で構文エラーが起きています。調べた限りだと、これはもうアロー関数を書き直すしか方法は無いのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、IE11はアロー関数に対応していないのでエラーが出ます。ただ、こちらでちょっと調べてみたところ、sweetalert2にアロー関数が使われている場所が（少なくとも配布版には）見つかりませんでした。sweetalert2をどのように読み込んでいるか追記いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: お返事が遅くなり申し訳ありません。正確にはsweetalert2を呼び出すjs部分にアロー関数を使っていました。書き直すしかないとのことですので、アロー関数を使用しないことで解決しました。ありがとうございました。